# How to add a software watchpoint following a breakpoint on gdb

Tags: python, c, gdb, breakpoints, watchpoint

I am trying to debug a C program which allocates and frees various instances of a particular structure during its lifetime. At some point, one of these instances is getting corrupted.

To debug it, I would like to set watchpoints shortly *after* these structures are allocated and remove the watchpoints shortly *before* they are free'd. For that, I wrote a python gdb script (see below) which implements two subclasses of `gdb.Breakpoint`: `BreakpointAlloc()` and `BreakpointFree()`. The former has a `stop()` method which adds a watchpoint on the allocated structure and the latter has a `stop()` method which removes the watchpoint. (Watchpoints are kept in a dict indexed by a string containing the address of the allocated instance.)

Due to the large number of instances allocated (over 100), I cannot use hardware watchpoints. When using software watchpoints (by first running `gdb.execute("set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0")`), however, the program seems to *wedge* and I can't tell what's happening.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gdb

wps = {}

def BreakpointAlloc(gdb.Breakpoint):
  def stop(self):
    ptr = gdb.parse_and_eval("ptr").address
    wp = gdb.Breakpoint("*({0})({1})".format(ptr.type, ptr), gdb.BP_WATCHPOINT)
    wps["{0}".format(ptr)] = wp
    return False

def BreakpointFree(gdb.Breakpoint):
  def stop(self):
    ptr = gdb.parse_and_eval("ptr").address
    wp = wps["{0}".format(ptr)]
    wp.delete()
    del wps["{0}".format(wp)]
    return False

bp_alloc = BreakpointAlloc("prog.c:111")
bp_free = BreakpointFree("prog.c:222")
gdb.execute("set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0")
```

The documentation for the gdb python API suggests you shouldn't do what I'm doing. I believe that may explain why the program is *wedging*:

> Function: **Breakpoint.stop** (*self*)
>
> ...
>
> You should not alter the execution state of the inferior (i.e., step, next, etc.), alter the current frame context (i.e., change the current active frame), or **alter, add or delete any breakpoint**.

Considering the documentation, I have also tried modifying my program to add/del the watchpoints via stop events (see below). When using software watchpoints, the same problem occurs: the program seems to *wedge*.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gdb

wps = {}

bp_alloc = gdb.Breakpoint("prog.c:111")
bp_free = gdb.Breakpoint("proc.c:222")

def stopAlloc():
  ptr = gdb.parse_and_eval("ptr").address
  wp = gdb.Breakpoint("*({0})({1})".format(ptr.type, ptr), gdb.BP_WATCHPOINT)
  wps["{0}".format(ptr)] = wp

def stopFree():
  ptr = gdb.parse_and_eval("ptr").address
  wp = wps["{0}".format(ptr)]
  wp.delete()
  del wps["{0}".format(ptr)]

def handleStop(stopEvent):
  for bp in stopEvent.breakpoints:
    if bp == bp_alloc:
      stopAlloc()
    elif bp == bp_free:
      stopFree()

gdb.events.stop(handleStop)
gdb.execute("set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0")
```

Any ideas on how I could manipulate watchpoints off breakpoints?

(Or any other ideas on how to debug this issue?)

Comment: Try to use `valgrind` or `rr` if possible.

Comment: @velkan: I've previously tried `record full` with gdb and it didn't work because my program is multi-threaded. Will look into `rr` some more and try `valgrind` as well.